# Android Studio verificar caracteres de un TextView

Tags: android-studio

estoy empezando con Android studio y tengo un problema quiero verificar que al introducir el nombre y apellidos haya caracteres sino avisar de que no ha puesto nada.

El código es el siguiente:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EAC1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView texto;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eac1);
    }

// Métodes dels botons!
    public void ResetTextNom (View vista){ //Hem creat aquest métode que el que fa es que al donar a la X esborri la info.
        TextView TexToResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextNom); //fem la variable TextoResultado es canvia per textNom
        TexToResultado.setText(""); // cambia el text actual a un " "
    }
// Ahora vamos hacer el TEXTVIEW.

    public void TextAcceptat (View vista){
        texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextNom); // Primer verifiquem el text i l'agafem
        if(texto ==null){ // Verifiquem que no estigui buït
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Heu d'escriure quelcom!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.show();
        }else{
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"bien!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast2.show();
        }
    }}
```

El problema lo tengo en la parte final en el if texto=null...

adjunto layout..

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TextNom"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="321dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"
        android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_co
```

Puede ser que me falte algo en el layout? En los botones hay que crear el android:onclick.. pero no sé si en los textos también..

gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien hagamos unas cuantas aclaraciones.

- En el layout tienes un `EditText` no un `TextView`.
- Estas enlazando el `EditText` que declaraste en el `layout` con un `TextView`. Tienes que enlazar el `EditText` del layout con un `EditText` no con un `TextView`.
- Estas creando dos variables del `EditText`, una en el metodo `ResetTextNom()` y otra en el metodo `TextAcceptat()`. Por lo que en ambos metodos estas trabajando con dos variables diferentes y los cambios que agas en una no afectaran a la otra. Si modificas el valor de la variable `TexToResultado`, el valor de la variable `texto` seguira siendo el mismo ya que son dos variables diferentes.

Solo tienes que declarar una variable del `EditText` en el método`onCreate()` de la clase y luego obtienes o modificas el valor de esa variable desde los métodos `ResetTextNom()` y `TextAcceptat()`.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EAC1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Declaras el EditText
    EditText texto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eac1);

        // Inicializas el EditText
        texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextNom);
    }

// Métodes dels botons!
    public void ResetTextNom (View vista){ //Hem creat aquest métode que el que fa es que al donar a la X esborri la info.
        //fem la variable TextoResultado es canvia per textNom
        // Modificas el valor del EditText
        texto.setText(""); // cambia el text actual a un " "
    }
// Ahora vamos hacer el TEXTVIEW.

    public void TextAcceptat (View vista){

        // Con getText() obtienes el texto del EditText.
        // Con toString() convierte el texto a String.
        // Con isEmpit() confirma si el EditText esta vacio. Si esta vacio retorna true.
        if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Heu d'escriure quelcom!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.show();
        }else{
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"bien!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast2.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: la parte:   if(texto.getText().isEmpit()) { me da error. No reconoce empit.  
Estoy empezando con Android y voy algo perdida, había mezclado los textView con los EditText.. Creo que muchas horas al ordenador me están matando.

Comment: disculpa, es un error mio. Ya lo corrijo.

Comment: @MontseMkd     Ya edite la respuesta, prueba de nuevo y me dejas saber.

Comment: no me funciona, pero leyendo por internet lo he conseguido al fin. Es poniendo esto:    String textoFin = texto.getText().toString();
        if (textoFin.isEmpty()) { . Así ya lo tengo perfecto, otro error que tenía era dentro de strings.xml tenía :  <string name="name">" "</string> al tener ese espacio lo que hacía era que de por si tenía un carácter. Bueno he aprendido mucho en este rato! xD  Gracias!!!

Comment: Lo que haces es lo mismo que yo hice en la corrección de mi respuesta. Lo único que tu lo haces en dos pasos y yo lo hice en uno. Pero es lo mismo. Tu manera puede ser un poco mas clara que la mía, solo eso. Pero al final cada quien trabaja de la manera que mas le guste. Me alegras que hayas aprendido. Así es el mundo de la programación, se aprende corrigiendo errores XD ;).

Comment: Gracias de verdad. Y por las explicaciones me ayudan mucho!!